# Xamarin Forms Relative Layout won't stack

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

With the following code:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0">
            <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="0">
                <BoxView Color="Blue" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" 
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" 
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Green" Padding="0">
                <BoxView Color="Yellow" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" 
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" 
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

But for some reason, instead of stacking, each new relative layout takes up the whole screen like this:

[image]

Why won't they stack up vertically? Stack layouts would normally only take vertically or horizontally the combined height of their children, but this doesn't happen with relative layouts. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this layout. I added StackLayout in ScrollView and VerticalOptions="Start" for RelativeLayouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TestChat.ChatPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0">
    <StackLayout>
            <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <BoxView Color="Blue" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" 
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" 
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Green" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <BoxView Color="Yellow" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" 
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" 
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: StackLayout FTW. I basically only use that and Grid (SL developer day time)